# How can I print each element of this Python list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm trying to make this code print out the names. However, CodeAcademy says that it is wrong perhaps it because I have `""` around the names around them when they are printed. What I wonder is how do I print out each name line by line. I'm thinking I need to use `len`.

```
 names = ["Adam","Alex","Mariah","Martine","Columbus"]
 for x in [names]:
     print x
```

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there; don't make `names` a nested list:

```
for x in names:
    print x
```

You are *nesting* the `names` list; you put it inside another list, which then has just one element. Looping over that will run once, and print the whole list object.

In other words, `names` is *already* a list, and the `for` statement will loop over it directly without any extra list syntax.

Comment: Attention to detail. The devil is in the detail when it comes to programming :0

Answer (score 2):

just remove `[` and `]` around `names` variable i.e

```
for x in names:
```

that would print what you have asked for.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that...CodeAcademy didn't accept that. I"m going to see if I can make it print names line by line.

Comment: @RobB.: CodeAcademy has known problems and errors. Do check their forums if you run into strange inconsistent errors, and try things out in a Python interpreter. It is really easy to install your own.

Comment: @MartijnPieters English is not my mother tongue.I hope `around` indicates that be in for loop.Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Much better; examples make it all the much clearer what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating an extra list. You should just be doing:

```
for x in names:
```